# Occurrence of the theoretical thymine enol::guanine base pair in DNA

Tags: molecular-biology, dna

DNA polymerase has a proofreading exonuclease activity that can remove incorrect tautomers in the DNA template or incoming base. In theory the enol form of thymine can form three hydrogen
bonds with guanine. Why is this base pair not favored in nature?

Comment: This is surely just a chemistry question — "why is the keto form of thymidine more stable than the enol form?" If there is almost no enol form there can be almost no base pairing involving this form.  In which case your question should be migrated to SE Chemistry. Or do I misunderstand you?